# if statements and else for python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on learning to code and have started with python, using python 3.6 on a Mac. I am working on the codes:

```
name = ('What is your name?:')        
if name == 'Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice.')
elif age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
elif age > 2000:
    print('Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')
elif age > 100:
    print('You are not Alice, grannie')
```

I keep getting an error saying 'age is not defined' I am reading the code exactly as it is written in the book.

Comment: What's the problem? There's no question here. The only thing I can note is that the last condition will never be true, since 2000 > 100.

Comment: You reference the variable *age*, but it seems you never assign it a value.

Comment: I miss wrote the code regarding the 2000>100 it should read 2000<100. When I assign it a value is it similar to the name= input()?

Answer (score 0):

Assign age value
    age = input("What is your age? ")

Answer (score 0):

In the provided code snippet, you are referring to an `age` variable, which you are then using for comparison purposes in your if statements. However, your code snippet does not contain an initial definition for the `age` variable, hence the `age is not defined` error message.

In Python, you must define a variable with an initial value before you can use the variable elsewhere (similarly to how you have handled the `name` variable).